Can the earths rotation around the sun create perpetual motion on earth?
As the earth rotates around the sun there are natural cycles of freezing and thawing of water in situe on earth because of the seasons this rotation causes.
When this in situe water freezes it expands and when it thaws it contracts.
If a volume of this water was hermetically sealed but the container could expand, could this natural expansion and contraction be used to create perpetual motion, at least until the sun goes supernova.
The force over the motion in the increase in volume, and the motion from the decrease in volume, could be used to work a device that creates a force over a motion that needs the same energy per year than the total energy of the force over the motion that the freezing and thawing of the water creates each year.
As such the motion of the device would at least continue from now until the sun goes supernova without any extra input of energy or work.
Or until the world freezes over.
So in principle and practice, is it possible via this system to create perpetual motion on earth?
Is perpetual motion, or motion itself a concern of phillosophy?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_motion#:~:text=Philosophy%20of%20motion%20is%20a,exists%2C%20how%20does%20it%20occur
My thinking may be flawed and I hope the community may be able to point out those flaws.

This seems like an exceedingly inefficient way to generate energy. We already use the energy generated by the sun and moon (and resulting processes) for "perpetual motion" through solar power, and wind power, and hydro power. But when people talk about perpetual motion, they're talking about a closed system (relatively speaking), so the above things wouldn't apply.

This sounds like a physics question (although I don't expect the [physics.se] site would take too kindly to this question). Philosophy of motion underlies science, whereas you're asking for applied science to evaluate the viability of a particular device, which is a completely different domain.

This is a physics question, not a philosophy one (so you might get better answers reframing it for physics stackexchange). "Can you extract energy from the seasons" is a totally valid physics question, and in theory, the answer is yes. But, in practice, the amount of work you can extract from it is probably a lot less than from other sources, like the moon (tidal power) or sunlight (solar, wind, water in dams).

Related: Utilize freezing water to generate energy (okay, maybe it isn't exceedingly inefficient)

This is a purely physics question. Please don't abuse the tags "philosophy-of-[whaterver crosses my mind]" to post questions about whatever crosses your mind on Philosophy SE. Also, this is no way a perpetual motion since it relies on a continuous flow of energy from the sun to melt the ice. Seasons on Earth are provoked by the energy flow of the sun being capted more or less efficiently depending on where one is on the surface. If the earth was orbiting a body emitting no light, there would be no seasons. You might as well put a wheel on a solar panel and call it perpetual motion.

@armand first of all there are no recorded planets that exclusively orbit black bodies and not stars. Please feel free to educate me if there are. We orbit a star. If the condition of perpetual motion does not include energy from the sun or indeed any other body that is hot such as the universe. Then the question of perpetual motion is moot.. In which case the only perpetual motion is the universe itself, unless it ends in no motion and has a beginning,  also you obviously didn't take a look at the body of the question which contained a link. Motion is a concern of philosophy!!

@NotThatGuy Thankyou. Freezing water creates a massive amount of pressure enough to create potholes in a solid tarmac road.!!

Look up "The Clock of the Long Now"

As I said, if you need to continuously bring energy into the system it's not perpetual motion, it's motion. You might as well call a solar panel feeding an engine, or a bicycle for that matter, perpetual motion machines. The notion of perpetual motion is indeed moot, that's why no physicist works on it except a quack from time to time, and reputable scientific journals rejects papers about it without consideration. Whether there are actually planets orbiting stars who do not emit energy is completely irrelevant.

@armand Well I'd rather be a quack than a ducky!! Sorry blackadder reference lol.

First, note that what you describe is not a perpetual motion machine. It is instead a special type of heat engine. The amount of useful work to be extracted from a freeze-thaw engine like this based on water is very small on a per-cycle basis, and difficult to capture mechanically because the effort variable is huge and the flow variable is tiny in comparison.
Note also that the maximum possible efficiency of any heat engine is established by the equation
(efficiency) = (Th - Tc)/(Th x Tc) where
Th = the high temperature in the system and Tc is the temperature at which the system exhausts its waste heat, both expressed in degrees absolute.  Since in this case (Th - Tc) is just a few degrees, this engine will output a vanishingly small amount of useful work for every unit of thermal energy it processes.
A far better solution is to use solar heat to evaporate that water, let it fall as rain in a mountain lake, and use it to spin a turbine wheel on its way downstream.
